# Why can't I draw on top of a UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, cgcontext

I've seen a few examples of drawing on top of a UIImage and I think I've followed the code exactly but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong? This code is in the action function for a button. The two images that get saved are identical. I would have expected one of them to have a white line drawn in it. Thank you. Code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext((uiImage?.size)!)
uiImage?.draw(at: CGPoint(x:0,y:0))
let newContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
newContext.setLineWidth(2)
newContext.move(to: CGPoint(x:10,y:10))
newContext.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:150,y:150))
newContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
newContext.strokePath()
finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(uiImage!, nil, nil, nil)
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(finalImage!, nil, nil, nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you're using the incorrect UIGraphics. You seem to be using:

```
finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentContext()
```

You may want to try:

```
finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

You may also want to call those methods **BEFORE** calling `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`. Make sure that is the last line

**EDIT:**
Here is my code for a drawing and saving an image. Hope this helps.

```
var imageToSave: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil)
    }
}

func drawLine(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint: CGPoint) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0)

    backgroundImageView.image?.draw(in: view.bounds)

    let drawContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    drawContext?.move(to: CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y: fromPoint.y))
    drawContext?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))

    drawContext?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    drawContext?.setLineWidth(brushWidth)
    drawContext?.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
    drawContext?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
    drawContext?.strokePath()

    imageToSave = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was a typo on my part. I am using
    finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

I also moved the UIGraphicsEndImageContext() command to after the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotoAlbum() calls. Unfortunately nothing changed. Thank you for the suggestions though!

Comment: @PaulK. I've edited my answer and added my own code for drawing and saving an image. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. I added this line by line to see what would make the difference and it turned out to be changing:
    uiImage?.draw(at: CGPoint(x:0,y:0))
to:
    uiImage?.draw(in: previewView.bounds)

I now have an image that has a line drawn on it. One strange thing though is that the image is about 1/4 of the size of the original image. Not sure why but from here I can play around. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: After playing around with the code I found that the image you get at the end depends heavily on the CGSize that you pass in to UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()
I was using the uiImage.size which has values of 1088 for x (width) and 1920 for y (height) but found that I get it just right when I use previewView.bounds.size which has a width of 375 and a height of 667. Mark this as solved!